PeerJs on Meta Quest Browser
I created a simple PeerJs application following this guide: https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/building-an-internet-connected-phone-with-peerjs-775bd6ffebec
If I connect between PC & PC or PC & mobile it works fine. But on the Meta Quest browser it does not work. Any suggestions on why?
What I will eventually try to do is to stream a babylon.js canvas to another device. Anyone with experience that could help me?
The following is the simple peerjs app:
import './App.css';

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Peer from 'peerjs';

function App() {

  const [peerId, setPeerId] = useState('');
  const [remotePeerIdValue, setRemotePeerIdValue] = useState('');
  const remoteVideoRef = useRef(null);
  const currentUserVideoRef = useRef(null);
  const peerInstance = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const peer = new Peer();

    peer.on('open', (id) => {
      setPeerId(id)
    });

    peer.on('call', (call) => {
      var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia 
      || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
      || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

      getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, (mediaStream) => {
        currentUserVideoRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
        currentUserVideoRef.current.play();
        call.answer(mediaStream)
        call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
          remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = remoteStream
          remoteVideoRef.current.play();
        });
      });
    })
  peerInstance.current = peer;
  }, [])

  const call = (remotePeerId) => {
    var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia 
    || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
    || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, (mediaStream) => {

      currentUserVideoRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
      currentUserVideoRef.current.play();

      const call = peerInstance.current.call(remotePeerId, mediaStream)

      call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
        remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = remoteStream
        remoteVideoRef.current.play();
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Current user id is {peerId}</h1>
      <input type="text" value={remotePeerIdValue} onChange={e => setRemotePeerIdValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => call(remotePeerIdValue)}>Call</button>
      <div>
        <video ref={currentUserVideoRef} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <video ref={remoteVideoRef} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

